# error while creating a bat file for starting the tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, batch-file

I am trying to create a bat file for copying the war file to webapps and then starting the startup.sh

my bat file is

```
echo start up
using CATALINA _HOME:"D:\codeBase\apache-tomcat-6.0.32"
set START_SERVER="D:\codeBase\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\bin\startup.bat"

xcopy D:\codeBase\gitCheckout\regression_dashboard\target\rd-test.war D:\codeBase\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\webapps
pause

call %START_SERVER%
```

i have set the CATALINA _HOME in enviornment variable and set the path too ( til /bin)

is there any where i need to set the catalina?? my output is something like this[image]

i tried without setting CATALINA_HOME in bat file. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

I see two *possible* problems:

```
using CATALINA _HOME:"D:\codeBase\apache-tomcat-6.0.32"
```

The first is that `using` is not in any way standard `cmd.exe`. I'm not sure where it's coming from but, in `cmd`, you would simply use `set`, like you have with `START_SERVER`, perhaps something like:

```
set CATALINA_HOME=D:\codeBase\apache-tomcat-6.0.32
```

The second is that there is a space before the underscore `_`. Even if `using` is in some way valid, that space is likely to be fatal to your expectation of setting `CATALINA_HOME`.

Comment: thanks.. it worked with set catalina_home .. "Using" was a trouble maker

Comment: @codenut, I've made lamer ones :-) Just out of interest, which one was it?